# 2006 Mercedes E350 4matic , v6 engine

Tags: engine, fuel-system, coolant, mercedes-benz, pump

Drove kids to school , stop to get ha and made it home then was about to leave back out and the car started to drive sluggish as if it didn't want to do . I proceeded to pull over at a gas station and once I stop I turned the car off . I tried cranking it back up and it would crank but die right back out !  Left it at the store for 2 days because had no other way to move it . And when I went back it wouldn't even crank up it sounded Like it was just trying to turn over ! And now I have a red coolant symbol under where my temperature hand is and my temperature  hand has dropped all the way down ! I also looked under the hood and where my anti freeze or water go was completely empty and there was a yellow looking goop under the top ! ?? what is wrong with my car? Is it something major like fuel pump ?  Or does it need water

Comment: Worst case, your motor is seized, which is significantly more major than a fuel pump.

Comment: Seized ? What does that mean ???

Comment: The motor could be internally damaged so it won't turn, meaning a rebuild or swapping out for another similar(used, probably) motor, or scrapping the entire car. [Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2vALliYg3Y) showing what it sounds like- a strong clank when you work the starter, not the weak click-clic-click when the battery is dying.